# SliverAppBar - SliverList is Scrolling all the way to the top

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, flutter-appbar

I am currently working with SliverAppBar and i am facing problem while Scrolling the sliverList.

[image]

In the Picture above, my TabBar is going all the way up to the notification bar. When sliverAppBar collapse, I want my Tabbar to stick to the bottom of the AppBar.

Here is my Code that i am trying...

```
    return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(

    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), onPressed: () {}),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share), onPressed: () {})
        ],
        floating: false,
        pinned: true,
        expandedHeight: getHeight(context),
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text("text"),
          background: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(currentImage),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(bottomListView),
      ),
    ],
  )
  ,
);
```

Comment: Do you want TabBar to always be under the appbar?

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin Yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use *bottom* parameter of *SliverAppBar* and pass *TabBar* to it. In *FlexibleSpaceBar* add *titlePadding* to add padding from the TabBar. If you need to change TabBar colour, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566868/how-to-change-background-color-of-tabbar-without-changing-the-appbar-in-flutter).

Be careful with a title inside FlexibleSpaceBar and action icons in AppBar, because long title will cause overlapping in minimized appbar.

```dart
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          //backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), onPressed: () {}),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share), onPressed: () {})
          ],
          floating: false,
          pinned: true,
          expandedHeight: getHeight(context),
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text("text"),
            // Adding padding from TabBar
            titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 64, left: 60),
            background: Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(currentImage),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            ),
          ),
          // Adding TabBar to the bottom of SliverAppBar
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                Tab(
                  text: 'test $i',
                ),
            ]
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(bottomListView),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: I wrapped TabBarVIew with Container and gave it white color. So, i dont have to change the primary color of whole app. It's an alternate way... But, it works thanks...

Answer (score 0):

its maybe a bug：

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22393

so you can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_nested_scroll_view),it solved this problem.